# Problem at proof of Cartan's theorem about the relation between metric and curvature in do Carmo's book

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm reading DoCarmo's book, Riemannian Geometry and i don't understand something. At page 157, Cartan's theorem.[image]

My question is, why can we take a Jacobi field $J$ in such a way that $J(0)=0$ and $J(l)=v?$

Comment: Any time you have a second-order differential equation on an interval, you can *either* specify the value and derivative at a single point *or* specify the values at two different points of the domain. We're just used to doing the former all the time :)

Comment: @TedShifrin ohh I didn't know that. I know that I can specify the value and the derivative at a point but i didn't know the second method. Can you give me some reference on this topic? something that i could read about? Thanks

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin: What you are saying is not true. Just look at the Jacobifields on $S^2$ when they reach the antipodal point.

Comment: Ted's claim needs some qualifying to become a theorem, but I'd say it's morally/generically true. In the case of the Jacobi equation, linearity tells us that it's true so long as the points $p,q$ are not conjugate, which is the case here since $V \ni q$ is a normal neighbourhood of $p.$

Answer (score 1):

A Jacobi field $J$ with initial conditions $J(0)=0$ and $J‘(0)=w$ along the geodesic $\gamma(t)=exp_p(tv)$ can explicitly be written as
\begin{equation}
J(t)=(d exp_p)_{tv}(tw).
\end{equation}
For small enough $t$ the differential of the exponential map at $tv$ is bijective. So for any $\nu \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$ there is some $u \in T_pM$ with 
\begin{equation}
(d exp_p)_{tv}(u)=\nu.
\end{equation}
Then the Jacobi field with initial condition $J(0)=0$ and $J‘(0)=\frac{u}{t}$ is the one you‘re looking for.